# Flow - combination of strings

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I'm using flow type-checker in my react project. I have a component like below:

```
// @flow
import React, { type Node } from 'react';

type Props = {
  isLoading?: boolean,
  children: Node,
  modifier: '' | '--medium' | '--dark' | '--green',
}

const PulsingCircleLoader = ({ children, isLoading, modifier }: Props) => (
  isLoading ?
    <div class={`PulsingCircleLoader ${modifier}`}>
      <div class="double-bounce1" />
      <div class="double-bounce2" />
    </div>
    :
    <span>{children}</span>
);

PulsingCircleLoader.defaultProps = {
  isLoading: false,
  modifier: '',
};
```

I use `modifier` prop to toggle styling of my component. Now I want to defend myself from receiving `blahblah` as modifier, but I would like to recevie: `'' or '--medium' or '--dark' or '--green'` **or combination of them like:**  `--medium --green`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You must use a composite type, because you can't append literal types like string values to form a new, combined type. Try it with a tuple for instance, kind of like `['--light', '--red']`

Comment: @ftor an array could be a solution, could you provide an example?

Comment: First, I'd try to separate the orthogonal types: e.g. `Brightness`/`Color`, because a combination of `--green` and `--blue` probably doesn't make sense. Then you can combine them in a tuple. [Try](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAQgTgSwOYAtgDsIGctQLxQDkhUAPkQLQUA2yaJ5hVAthACYICuzDlFbAQzgBrQgG4AUKEhQAwgHtq8uPiK8mFOO3VUkWiOl4AiAEbVOEI5KnhoAWXkcAZgggqCAbXh0M2LABo5RWUAXWsAY3l0LGAoZkcEFzcoAC4HZ1d3KA8NWlRgQkCNLTZCMKA). Please note that a tuple isn't an array, at least from a type level perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UnionType` like this:

```
type Modifier = '' | '--medium' | '--dark' | '--green';
```

And type Props will be:

```
type Props = {
  isLoading?: boolean,
  children: Node,
  modifiers: Modifier[],
}
```

And use it like:

```
const PulsingCircleLoader = ({ children, isLoading, modifiers }: Props) => (
  isLoading ?
    <div class={`PulsingCircleLoader ${modifiers.join(' ')}`}>
      <div class="double-bounce1" />
      <div class="double-bounce2" />
    </div>
    :
    <span>{children}</span>
);
```

Comment: I know about union types but I was hoping to avoid explicitly declaring each combination. With only three modifiers it will make 9 possible combinations. Though it might be the only solution...

Comment: Yeah i know... Let's see maybe there is a better solution from to cover all possible solutions with union.

Comment: @Tomasz u can try something like this: https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoALgTwA4FMwCycAJgJZSm4BOYAvGAOQNgA+jAtOwLa5kCuXZmwadiAQyoBrIR3YBzKrlwA7BgG4MOfAAUqcbAGc6YAN6owYUgYAycMWWVyA-AC4wAIzhwYuMcoA05mBcJOSUVG4A2kRkFNT+hKFxVAC6CcDAYAAqfNg+qAC+qMUAxnDKBuhg6LiVbrr6RvRmFla29qSObuhUfLiBFiGx4VEi3LykAgwJYwpKqilgGWBQcDQGnXI+YABuYjB9YJFjPPyCMwwphcWoQA

Comment: well, an array of modifiers could be the thing I'm looking for. I mean `modifiers: Modifier[]` should be good enough.